# How to extract two rgb values/strings from the another string using regex or another method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

The following string has been retrieved from an element's style attribute, the attribute is a variable and can contain different colors in a particular vertical gradient background:

`string = "background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(100, 106, 237) 0%, rgb(101, 222, 108) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; display: list-item; cursor: pointer;"`

Using the following code, the linear-gradient contents is extracted from the string:

`string = string.substring(string.indexOf('linear-gradient('), 1+string.lastIndexOf(')')); // string = "linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(100, 106, 237) 0%, rgb(101, 222, 108) 100%)"`

Now using a regular expression -or any other method- I need to extract both the first rgb -`rgb(100, 106, 237)`- value as-well as the second -`rgb(101, 222, 108)`. Can anyone please recommend/suggest a simple method to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
string.replace(/^.*?linear-gradient *\((.+)/, function($1, $2) {
                         return $1.match(/rgb *\([^)]+\)/g); } );
//=> rgb(100, 106, 237),rgb(101, 222, 108)
```

Assuming there is no other `rgb` segment outside closing bracket of `linear-gradient`

Comment: what if there was a mix of rgb & rgba ?

Comment: Then use `rgba?` in regex

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regular expression to extract all rgb codes:

```
var regex = /rgb\(([^\)]+)\)/g;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for your first extracting. Try the following:

```
var re = /rgb\(\d{1,3}, ?\d{1,3}, ?\d{1,3}\)/g;

// and then get array of matches

var rgbs = string.match(re);

//It will be equal to null if there is no matches.
```